# I have a question about .coords in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def move_pad(): 
    pads = {RIGHT_PAD: RIGH_PAD_SPEED, LEFT_PAD: LEFT_PAD_SPEED} 
    for pad in pads: 
        c.move(pad, 0, pads[pad]) 
        if c.coords(pad)[1] < 0: 
            c.move(pad, 0, -c.coords(pad)[1]) 
        elif c.coords(pad)[3] > HEIGHT: 
            c.move(pad, HEIGHT, -c.coords(pad)[3])
```

Can someone explain why we need here this[3] or [1] in c.coords(pad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain why we need here this[3] or [1] in c.coords(pad)

`coords` returns a tuple of four values. `c.coords(pad)[1]` refers to the upper-left y coordinate and `c.coords(pad)[3]` refers to the lower-right y coordinate.

Comment: You've edited the Q right? The indentation still appears to be wrong?

Comment: @CoolCloud: ah, yes, I see there are more indentation errors. Thanks for letting me know.